# Android action bar only on tablet

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have the following question:

I have created an app and it should run on phone and tablet (same app). Now when i'm on an small screen i want to use the hard 'settings button' to pop up the menu but when on tablet (without settings button) i want to show an action bar?

I don't want the action bar on the small screen because it takes space

When the activity starts i use the following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Now when i'm on an small screen i want to use the hard 'settings button' to pop up the menu

There is no "settings button" on Android devices. There *may* be a MENU button on some devices, but not all, including not all phones. In fact, most Android 4.x device models do not have a MENU button -- Samsung is one of the few manufacturers still using them.

> I don't want the action bar on the small screen because it takes space

There are millions of "small screen" devices that do not have a MENU button. What you want will prevent those devices from using your app, as they will have no means of getting to your menu.

Hence, do not use an action bar on any Android device, and display your own menu written with your own widgets, triggered by your own chosen means (e.g., a trigger button, a gesture).

Comment: hmm I didn't think off that, maybe i could use a 'slide down' menu, i will check it